# whenever i use either loadextension or select load extension it gives Internal server error(sqlite3,spatialite,PHP windows)

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, gis, spatialite

Please help. I've also given the code below. Tried so many things. Isn't working.

selected a spatialite database:

```
     $db = new SQLite3('db2.sqlite');
```

tried these load extensions:

```
// $db->loadExtension('C:\PHP\ext\libspatialite-2.dll');
//   $db->loadExtension('libspatialite-4.dll');
//   $db->exec("SELECT InitSpatialMetadata()");
```

also tried this function in case if loading extension is disabled:

```
// $db->exec("sqlite3_enable_load_extension(1)");
//   $tvalue=$db->loadExtension('C:\\PHP\\sqliteext\\libspatialite-4.dll');
```

tried load extension here:

```
    $db->exec("SELECT load_extension('C:\\PHP\\sqliteext\\libspatialite-4.dll')");
    phpinfo();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT load_extension('libspatialite-4.dll')");


    var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

tried this query:

```
    $result = $db->query('select astext(geometry) from roads');
    var_dump($result->fetchArray());

    $rs = $db->query('SELECT spatialite_version()');
```

Comment: What failed? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common problems is using a version of libspatialite that is an "amalgamation" build, which includes sqlite. That is problematic (especially on 64 bit windows) if the version of sqlite that is included doesn't match the version that you're using to load libspatialite. Two versions with different ABI = crash.

I don't have a nice solution, but there are things you can do to try to avoid this:
1. don't use an amalgamation build
2. make sure that the two versions of sqlite are the same.